# LogicApp via ARM to Listen Dropbox ( trigger ) to FTP ( action )

Tags: azure, azure-deployment, azure-rm-template

Would there be any ARM template for listening to a dropbox folder and creating file in FTP. I do find templates in azure on blob to FTP.

Also, what would be the Dropbox connection resource be in the deploy template? From where could i get these details in documentaion.

Please find my deploy json as below

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
  "dropboxconnectionaccountname": {
  "type": "string",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "Account name of the dropbox."
  }
},
"dropboxpassword": {
  "type": "securestring",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "Password for the dropbox account"
  }
},
"dropboxconnectionname": {
  "type": "string",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "The name of the Dropbox connection being created."
  }
},
"ftpServerAddress": {
  "type": "string",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "The address of the FTP server."
  }
},
"ftpUsername": {
  "type": "string",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "The username for the FTP server."
  }
},

 "ftpPassword": {
  "type": "securestring",
  "metadata": {
"description": "The password for the FTP server."
          }
},
"ftpServerPort": {
  "type": "int",
  "defaultvalue": 21,
  "metadata": {
    "description": "The port for the FTP server."
  }
},

"ftpconnectionname": {
  "type": "string",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "The name of the FTP connection being created."
  }
},  

"logicAppName": {
  "type": "string",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "The name of the logic app to create."
  }
},
"flowSkuName": {
  "type": "string",
  "defaultValue": "Standard",
  "allowedValues": [
    "Free",
    "Basic",
    "Standard",
    "Premium"
  ],
  "metadata": {
    "description": "The pricing tier for the logic app."
  }
},
"hostingPlanName": {
  "type": "string",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "The name of the App Service plan to create for hosting the logic app."
  }
},
"hostingSkuName": {
  "type": "string",
  "defaultValue": "S1",
  "allowedValues": [
    "F1",
    "D1",
    "B1",
    "B2",
    "B3",
    "S1",
    "S2",
    "S3",
    "P1",
    "P2",
    "P3",
    "P4"
  ],
  "metadata": {
    "description": "Describes plan's pricing tier and instance size."
  }
},
"hostingSkuCapacity": {
  "type": "int",
  "defaultValue": 1,
  "minValue": 1,
  "metadata": {
    "description": "Describes plan's instance count"
  }
},
"testUri": {
  "type": "string",
  "defaultValue": "http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/feed/",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "A test URI"
  }
}
  },
 "variables": {
"$ftpisssl": true,
"$ftpisBinaryTransport": true,
"$ftpdisableCertificateValidation": true

  },
  "resources": [
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
  "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "name": "[parameters('dropboxconnectionname')]",
  "properties": {
    "api": {
      "id": "[concat(subscription().id,'/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', resourceGroup().location, '/managedApis/dropbox')]"
    },
    "displayName": "dropbox",
    "parameterValues": {
      "email": "[parameters('dropboxconnectionaccountname')]",
      "password": "[parameters('dropboxpassword')]"
    }
  }
}, 
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
  "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "name": "[parameters('ftpconnectionname')]",
  "properties": {
    "api": {
      "id": "[concat(subscription().id,'/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', resourceGroup().location, '/managedApis/ftp')]"
    },
    "displayName": "ftp",
    "parameterValues": {
      "serverAddress": "[parameters('ftpServerAddress')]",
      "userName": "[parameters('ftpUsername')]",
      "password": "[parameters('ftpPassword')]",
      "serverPort": "[parameters('ftpServerPort')]",
      "isssl": "[variables('$ftpisssl')]",
      "isBinaryTransport": "[variables('$ftpisBinaryTransport')]",
      "disableCertificateValidation": "[variables('$ftpdisableCertificateValidation')]"
    }
  }
},
{
  "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
  "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "tags": {
    "displayName": "HostingPlan"
  },
  "sku": {
    "name": "[parameters('hostingSkuName')]",
    "capacity": "[parameters('hostingSkuCapacity')]"
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]"
  }
},
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
  "apiVersion": "2015-08-01-preview",
  "name": "[parameters('logicAppName')]",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', parameters('dropboxconnectionname'))]",
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', parameters('ftpconnectionname'))]"
  ],
  "tags": {
    "displayName": "LogicApp"
  },
  "properties": {
    "sku": {
      "name": "[parameters('flowSkuName')]",
      "plan": {
        "id": "[concat(resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/',parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
      }
    },
    "definition": {
            "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
            "actions": {
                "Create_file": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "body": "@triggerBody()",
                            "host": {
                                "api": {
                                    "runtimeUrl": "[concat('https://logic-apis-', resourceGroup().location, '.azure-apim.net/apim/ftp')]"
                                },
                                "connection": {
                                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['ftp']['connectionId']"
                                }
                            },
                            "method": "post",
                            "path": "/datasets/default/files",
                            "queries": {
                                "folderPath": "/site/wwwroot/",
                                "name": "@{triggerOutputs()['headers']?['x-ms-file-name']}"
                            }
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "ApiConnection"
                    }
                },
                "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                "outputs": {},
                "parameters": {
                    "$connections": {
                        "defaultValue": {},
                        "type": "Object"
                    }
                },
                "triggers": {
                    "When_a_file_is_added_or_modified": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "host": {
                                "api": {
                                    "runtimeUrl": "[concat('https://logic-apis-', resourceGroup().location, '.azure-apim.net/apim/dropbox')]"
                                },
                                "connection": {
                                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['dropbox']['connectionId']"
                                }
                            },
                            "method": "get",
                            "path": "/datasets/default/triggers/onupdatedfile",
                            "queries": {
                                "folderId": "/site/wwwroot"
                            }
                        },
                        "recurrence": {
                            "frequency": "Second",
                            "interval": 15
                        },
                        "type": "ApiConnection"
                    }
                }
        },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
        "value": {
          "ftp": {
            "id": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.Web/connections/', parameters('ftpconnectionname')), '2015-08-01-preview').api.id]",  
            "connectionName": "[parameters('ftpconnectionname')]",
            "connectionId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', parameters('ftpconnectionname'))]"
          },
          "dropbox": {
            "id": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.Web/connections/', parameters('dropboxconnectionname')), '2015-08-01-preview').api.id]",  
            "connectionName": "[parameters('dropboxconnectionname')]",
            "connectionId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', parameters('dropboxconnectionname'))]"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
 ],
 "outputs": {}
}
```

Comment: I attempted created a deploy json but get the following error at connection resource object `New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 4:01:25 PM - Resource Microsoft.Web/connections 'dropboxconn' failed with message '{"Code":"BadRequest","Message":"Input parameters are 
invalid. See details for more information. Details:errorCode: ParameterNotDefined. Message: Parameter  'userName' is not allowed on the connection since it was not defined as a 
connection parameter when the API was registered..","Target":null,"Details":[{"Message":"Input parameters are invalid.

Comment: Looks like at moment only FTP and Blob or verse is supported from ARM template.. means we have to go to portal manually and setup the connection and rules. Any suggestion or solution please

Comment: Any update on this issue ???

Comment: @Thomas Sorry for late reply. At that point of time, I got the following clarification from MS Support but not able to recollect at this point why I didnt attempt further. Let me re-attempt and identify update in next few days. [ From MSupport Scribble : After GA, Logic Apps V1 Connectors are not available on the portal. So if you need to use the V1 connectors, you would need to use them through ARM templates. But I would not recommend using V1 Connectors as they would soon be retired. ]